# How to prove $|H|[K:K \cap (g^{-1}Hg)]=|K|[H:H \cap (gKg^{-1})]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \leq G$, $K \leq G$. For an element $g \in G$, prove $$|H|[K:K \cap (g^{-1}Hg)]=|K|[H:H \cap (gKg^{-1})].$$

I am not sure where to start proving this. A hint would be helpful please.

Comment: Can I assume that g^-1Hg =H? Or only if it is normal?

Comment: Only if $H$ is a normal subgroup. This assumption is not necessary for the equality to hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left side, you have the number of elements in the double coset $HgK$. On the right side, you have the number of elements in the double coset $Kg^{-1}H$. Equality follows from the fact that $HgK = (Kg^{-1}H)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $H\cap gKg^{-1}=g(g^{-1}Hg\cap K)g^{-1}$ are equal hence the same size. Conjugation is injective.

Comment: Another hint. If $h,k,m,n$ are integers with $m=n$, then $\displaystyle h\frac{k}{m}=k\frac{h}{n}$.